# embedding gists from github in stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, markdown

Is there a way to embed the code put up on gist.github.com in either the question or the answer instead of repeating the same thing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That would be the same as linking, which means that should the gist disappear, the question/answer here becomes useless.

Won't fix.